# How did this question get deleted by "Community" so fast?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/14642/open-toe-shoes-in-the-workplace

How did this get deleted by Community so fast? Was it because the user was removed/deleted or something?

[image: This question was]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the user was deleted, causing the question to be deleted as well.

Users can delete themselves voluntarily, or be deleted for violations of the Terms of Service ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126471/167443)).

Comment: Well that was easy! :)

Comment: Under what conditions does a use get deleted?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The more common reasons for a moderator to delete an account is spam or extremely offensive posts _without_ any other positive contributions (if there are other positive contributions, suspension is preferable). Also, accounts of users under the age of 13 will be removed ([COPPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children's_Online_Privacy_Protection_Act))